# No subject alternative DNS name matching domain-name found

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, java-11, amazon-mq

Unable to connect to Amazon MQ using Openwire protocol with spring boot and Amazon MQ.

- Java - JDK11
- Spring Boot - 2.1.1.Release
- Amazon MQ - 1.15.9

I have tried to connect with tcp scheme also but no luck. Let me know if u need more info. Getting following exception.

````
Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@412f126d[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
Closed socket Socket[unconnected]
Forcing shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@412f126d[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
Waiting 2560 ms before attempting connection
Attempting 9th connect to: ssl://domain-name:61617
Sending: WireFormatInfo { version=12, properties={TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, CacheSize=1024, ProviderName=ActiveMQ, StackTraceEnabled=true, PlatformDetails=Java, CacheEnabled=true, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, ProviderVersion=5.15.8}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
Connect fail to: ssl://domain-name:61617, reason: {}
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching domain-name found.
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpBufferedOutputStream.flush(TcpBufferedOutputStream.java:115)```
````

Comment: Can you share your code snippet you are using to make a connection?

Comment: I am using QPIDJmsConnectionFactory to connect Amazon MQ. Also I am following this example to run the code

https://github.com/tabish121/qpid-jms-spring-boot/tree/master/qpid-jms-spring-boot-examples